# How to properly wrap a functional component with React.memo()? Still rerenders on every rerender of a parent component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

Code shortened to make it more readable.

In components/FunctionalComponent.js:

```
import React, {memo} from 'react'
//other necessary imports...

const FunctionalComponent = ({destructuredProps}) => {
   ...
   //some code that determines what and how the component behaves. Uses destructured props.
   ...
   return (
   <View>
      ...
      A lot of other elements
      ...
   </View>
   )
}

export default memo(FunctionalComponent);
```

It is important to note that some of the destructured props are callback functions, but those have been memoized using useCallback.

In main.js:

```
import React from 'react'
import FunctionalComponent from 'components/FunctionalComponent'

const MainComponent = () => {
   //some code that determines how component behaves
   return (
   <View>
      //Some other components
      <FunctionalComponent />
   </View>
   )
}

export default MainComponent
```

How should one go about wrapping such a component in memo() to prevent rerenders?

- I am using 'console.log('function rerendered') inside FunctionalComponent to see when it rerenders.

**Edit: Added more details**

The component is an auto-complete google maps search bar with some buttons and a map. It rerenders when I am interacting with elements on the screen that are not part of the props list passed to the search bar component, so it might be that I'm using the "useCallback" incorrectly. This is how the component is used.

```js
<AutoCompleteSearch
   term={searchTerm}
   onTermChange={setSearchTermCallBack}
   enabled = {isSearchBarEnabled}
   setResultDetail = {setResultDetailsCallBack}
/>
```

This is how I define the callbacks and the state variables:

```js
const [searchTerm, setSearchTerm] = useState('');
const setSearchTermCallBack = useCallback((term)=>setSearchTerm(term),[]);

const [resultDetails, setResultDetails] = useState({});
const setResultDetailsCallBack = useCallback((term)=>setSearchTerm(term),[]);
```

Search term and the setter is passed to the component because I need the information for the API request. The details setter is passed because I want to access and display parts of the information that the API call in the search bar returns.

Hope this makes things clearer.

Comment: If the component still gets rerendered then one of its props is changing. Since you are not providing a complete example that's all we can say about it really.

Comment: can you show us how you're calling `useCallback` ?

Comment: @azium I have updated the post, under the "Edit" section there is a bit more information. Hope this makes things easier to answer. Thanks for the reply!

Comment: @FelixKling As far as I know, when you pass a function returned from useCallback to  a component, it should equate as "equal" when `React.memo` checks to see if props have changed. I have added changes in the "Edit" section of the post for more info.

Comment: Seems fine to me, but note that *"React guarantees that setState function identity is stable and won’t change on re-renders."* (https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usestate) so if you are using `useCallback` just for the state setters, then you don't actually need them.

Comment: If you want more insights on what props are changing, you can pass a second argument to `memo`, that is your custom comparison function. You could use any shallow comparison function, such as lodash's `isEqual()`, and `console.log()` the `prevProps` and `newProps` inside the body of the function before returning the result.

Comment: @TheoAvoyne Thanks! I will definitely try that and see what is happening.